# NI Reaktor Audio Input Vertical Line

Tags: audio, reactive-programming

I recently restartet patching in Reaktor and found something strange. In one of my Primary structures there is an input pin switching its icon to vertical line every now and then when I edit the structure. It somehow depends on the audio processing sequence.

Unfortunately I cannot post an image of the structure, because this needs more reputation... however, does anyone know what is the point with this port? It feels spooky. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds to me like a audio loop indicator.

It appears if the signal flow is feed back so that it can't processed at the same time. In this case the feedback signal gets feed in one audio clock later. 
What means that this port has a delay of 1 sample.

In order to determine yourself where this delay applies you may insert the Unit Delay what does the same job (1 sample delay) but at the place you want.

Comment: Alright, thanks for enlightening me on this. Unit Delay does exactly what you described!